# How does one check if a Spark row or row.schema 'contains' a field name?

Tags: java, apache-spark

For example, I have a spark row:

```
Row row = ...
```

I can evaluate the following command in an interactive session with the debugger:

```
row.schema.fieldNamesSet.contains("title")
> true
```

However, I cannot write:

```
assertThat(row.schema.fieldNamesSet.contains("title"))
// or
assertThat(row.schema().fieldNamesSet.contains("title"))
// etc.

// this method path is not available because it has "private access"
```

(General question, or Y) How do I assert that a fieldName is not present in the row?

(Specific question, or X) How do I perform an in-line check whether a schema contains a fieldName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema of a `Row` is an instance of the `StructType` class, so you can refer to the [JavaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html) of this class to find out all the public fields and methods that you can use. Note that you can use all the methods defined in the `StructType` class plus all methods inherited from the superclasses and interfaces.

In particular, to verify if the schema contains or not a given field name you have various options:

###### `exists` method

Pass a predicate to the `exists` method that will be evaluated for each field and returns `true` if at least one field matches the condition. It is also useful if you want to evaluate other conditions besides the name.

```java
row.schema().exists(f -> "title".equals(f.name()));
```

###### `getFieldIndex` method

The `StructType.getFieldIndex` method returns an `Option` pointing to the actual field index if present, or to `None` if not present.

```java
row.schema().getFieldIndex("title").isDefined();
```

You can also access the fields or fieldNames arrays with the `fields()` and `fieldNames()` methods and process them as it is most convenient for your use case.